# Error while making a new command

Tags: packages, environments, line-spacing

I am making a new command which goes something like this

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```

When I use this command by the following code,

```
    \section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Indian Institute of Science Education and Research, Berhampur}{Aug. 2019 -- 2024}
      {3rd year BS-MS Undergraduate}{Berhampur, Odisha}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Puna International School}{2017-2019}
      {Higher Secondary}{Ahmedabad, Gujarat}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Airport Public School}{2015-2017}
      {Senior Secondary}{Ahmedabad, Gujarat}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

and I get following output
[image]

But now I want to add another line after "3rd year BS-MS Undergraduate". But when I do so, I'm getting this result
[image]
What should I do to make it not look like this?

Comment: please extend your example to a full example that others can copy and test as is. We have no idea where `  \resumeSubHeadingListStart` comes from so please complete the code so we can help

Comment: If you do not provide a usable test document it is hard to help, but any use of negative space such as `\vspace{-7pt}` is quite likely to produce overprinting as you show. TeX will almost never overprint vertically unless you add explicit instructions like this to force it to over-print.